# Disable "Name can be simplified" IDE0003 fix hint

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, roslyn

Visual Studio 2017 shows a hint for unnecessary `this` qualifiers even when the inspection is disabled in the options.

This is how it looks:
[image]
(First line is the culprit, second line is how I want `this` to *always* look like.)

Hovering over the grayed out `this` and clicking on the light bulb shows this suggested fix: 
[image]

I can't find a way of disabling this completely. Sometimes I want to have "unnecessary" `this` qualifiers and sometimes I don't, so I don't want VS to comment about this at all.

"None" is the least severe option yet it still shows this annoying, different color.
[image]

**Is there any possibility of complete disabling this inspection?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use a ruleset file to disable any analysis if you know its diagnostic id (in this case 'IDE0003')

1. On the `References` node of you project right click on `Analyzers` and select `Open Active Rule Set`
   [image]
2. Once the ruleset editor is open just search for `IDE0003` and uncheck the checkbox.  Then save the ruleset file.  Then save the project.

[image]

[image]

3. The following XML will be added to you project file.  You can add this ruleset file to any project where you want this rule disabled.

`<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>ConsoleApp9.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>`

Comment: I have 52 projects in my solution, a number which will grow.  Is there a more blanket-coverage option than having to establish and maintain this for every one of them?

Comment: You can include a default ruleset file in all of your projects via a targets file

Comment: @DonBoitnott - searching for how to do what Jonathon says, I found [MSBuild .targets files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-dot-targets-files?view=vs-2017). There, see links "Import element (MSBuild)" and "How to: Use the same target in multiple project files". Does involve adding an `Import` line to each project's proj file. So it may be just as easy to directly add a `CodeAnalysisRuleSet` line that refers to a ruleset in a common ("..\") location.

Comment: If you are using at least MSBuild 15 you can use [Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2017#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) and have it automatically imported into all of your projects

Comment: Is there a way to disable a rule in specific cases and leave it on in others? For instance, I get an IDE0002 error "Simplify Member Access". I want to ignore this rule when it suggests that I remove the static class from `MyStaticClass.Member`. Can this be done?

Comment: A Dotnet Core test project in VS2019 doesn't have References or Analyzer nodes. Where can I configure the rules for those project types?

Comment: Deleting the rule from my EditorConfig fixed it for me.

Comment: This is a nightmare for ten year old projects. I'd love to have some of these things fixed but it's too time consuming to fix them all and I fear it's the root of my high CPU from Roslyn analyzers. Also as soon as anyone says 'targets file' ..... :-/

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the current process is more complicated for .NET Core and .NET Standard projects.

From [MS VS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-create-a-custom-rule-set?view=vs-2019#create-a-custom-rule-set-from-an-existing-rule-set):

> ***If you have a .NET Core or .NET Standard project, the process is a little different*** because there's no Code Analysis property tab. [Follow the steps to copy a predefined rule set to your project and set it as the active rule set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-quality-rule-options). After you've copied over a rule set, you can [edit it in the Visual Studio rule set editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/working-in-the-code-analysis-rule-set-editor?view=vs-2019) by opening it from Solution Explorer. [emphasis mine]

Taking the first link in that quote will eventually take you, after a little sleuthing, to [Code style rule options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-style-rule-options), that finally tells you how to add the file:

> In Visual Studio, you can generate this file and save it to a project at **Tools > Options > Text Editor > [C# or Basic] > Code Style > General**. Then, click the **Generate .editorconfig file from settings** button.

[image: location of "Generate .editorconfig file from settings" button in VS settings]

> **NOTE:** This produces a *tiny* warning just under your toolbars that an `.editorconfig` has been added to your solution. Select the "Yes" button to include it in your solution.

And now you can open and edit your new `.editorconfig` file.

Looks like this is the "offending" section:

```
# this. and Me. preferences
dotnet_style_qualification_for_event = false:suggestion
dotnet_style_qualification_for_field = false:silent
dotnet_style_qualification_for_method = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_qualification_for_property = false:suggestion
```

If that `dotnet_style_qualification_for_property` **is changed to** `= true:suggestion` ([explanation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0003-ide0009#dotnet_style_qualification_for_property)), I think you're golden [at least for properties, of course -- make edits as appropriate].