# Disable Visual Studio code style recommendations

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, .net-5

Is there a way to get Visual studio to stop spamming me with these messages?

[image]

Visual Studio version info

[image]

I am also running Resharper 2021.1.2 which I have set up with the recommendations I want.

Comment: Do you have only messages with "IDE" there or also other groups that annoy you (such as "SA" or "SX"?

Comment: I get occasional `CS` messages. Resharper also reports those as errors.

Comment: `CS` are "real" compiler warnings. In C#, you should never ignore those (it's best practice to enable "treat warnings as errors"). If you really want to disable specific ones, you can add them to the "Ignore warnings" list in project settings.

Comment: For the IDE errors, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48857982/disable-name-can-be-simplified-ide0003-fix-hint might answer your question.

Comment: "CS are "real" compiler warnings" Right. However, both VS and Resharper both inform me of the error. https://imgur.com/a/5g1ahWW

Comment: That's true, and really a bit annoying. However I think that should be put into a different question, as it's likely independent of the IDE messages and therefore likely also has a different answer.

Comment: Additionally, I have no right click option on my Analyzers section in the Project.

Comment: Neither do I... Seems this has changed (that question is quite old already). I do have options to disable specific warnings when I unfold that node all the way down. Then it shows a line for all possible warnings.

Comment: It seems a lot of this changed over when Core (and subsequently .NET 5) was introduced.

Comment: Did you find an answer ?

Comment: I have not, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did for my .NET Framework project:

Open up the project properties, and click the `Code Analysis` tab. You'll see the active rule is `Microsoft Managed Recommended Rules`. To the right, there's a `Configure` button. Click that.

There's going to be a notice at the top saying "This is a Microsoft rule set and cannot be modified." That's ok. Click the dropdown for `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features` and uncheck all of the `IDE####` hints that are bothering you.

Hit ctrl+s to save your new ruleset. Because this is now a custom ruleset you will be prompted with a place to save it. You can save it anywhere and name it whatever you want.

Now, back in the `Code Analysis` tab in your project settings, click the `Active rules` dropdown. Second from the bottom there is a `<Browse...>` option. Choose that and select the .ruleset file you just saved in the previous steps.

For me my active rule is now `Copy of Microsoft Managed Recommended Rules`, so if you see that you're on the right track.

The IDE hints should now be gone!

I should add that something still didn't feel right with me. I eventually went through and deleted all my .dotsettings files and .editorconfig files, and reset my resharper settings (`Extensions -> Resharper -> Options... -> Manage... -> Reset All Settings`). This also fixed my unwanted hint problems.

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks